# Borders and Title Menus disappeared on ubuntu "pop-up" Modal windows

Tags: unity

I awoke this morning from uneasy dreams to find my Ubuntu 12.04's pop-ups transformed into a gigantic bug.

I'm not aware of having made any changes here, but the pop-ups look like this:

[image]

You can see there's no border around the pop-up, and no title menu allowing me to close or minimize it.

Same for Thunderbird password prompts, the menus in Gimp, etc., so it isn't localized to Browsers.  These are pretty important for operating with my windows, especially in Gimp.  What happened and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just your window manager (I'm guessing Unity) that crashed. Unless is not something big, just restarting should bring things to normal.

Answer (score 1):

Braiam is right, it is the window manager that's the problem, thus you only need to reinstall it (compiz for unity  or metacity for unity2d):

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall compiz
```

Alternatively, reconfiguring your xserver will usually also work.  I try this command pretty much any time I have graphical display issues, but you'll need to do this from one of the non-graphical ttys by pressing <kbd>ctrk</kbd> <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>F3</kbd> then typing:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Comment: Thanks, but didn't have to reinstall unity, only restart it.

Answer (score 0):

reinstalling unity may solve your problem,try these commands on terminal,

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Comment: That sounds very scary!

Comment: Thanks, but didn't have to reinstall unity, only restart it.

Answer (score 0):

The following are the solutions to my question:

- Restart computer

This has the effect of restarting unity, but is not the only way to restart unity.  Perhaps the user has unsaved work.

So, the procedure I used was instead:

- Restart unity

I additionally provided instructions to new ubuntu users who might not know how to do that. Open the terminal, type `unity`.

Comment: How would you advise people to exit terminal after typing unity ?

Comment: Yeah, I wondered that too, when I did it.  But it turned out closing the terminal forced unity to restart a second time, and was still fine.